# How to test a Java Library in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm looking for a way to test a java library. I never worked before with libraries written by me, and I'm trying to understand how to debug a java project without a main method. In particular, I took a java library that handles barcodes and I'm trying to change its contents. In the example version there is only a bar code, while I need to implement other types of bar codes. Since in the decompiled library imported into Eclipse there is no Main method to debug the content and see any errors. Operationally how can I do in Eclipse that execute the code, instead of each time exporting the jar file and replacing it in the classpath that containing the original library?

I looked for something online, but I didn't find an example tha t explains how to do.

```
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.CrystalResourcesFactory;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.value.FormulaValue;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.value.FormulaValueType;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.value.StringValue;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaFunction;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaFunctionCallException;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.FormulaValueReference;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.formulas.SimpleFormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition;

public abstract class CodeEAN13Base
   implements FormulaFunction
 {
   FormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition[] myArguments = { SimpleFormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition.string };

protected CrystalResourcesFactory resCrystal;



  public CodeEAN13Base()
   {
     this.resCrystal = new CrystalResourcesFactory("Messages");

   }


  protected final String doTranslation(String inputData,String opz)
 // protected final String doTranslation(String inputData)
   {
    String returnVal = "";

   //  returnVal = returnVal + translateCharWrapper(inputData);
     returnVal = returnVal + translateCharWrapper(inputData,opz);


    return returnVal;
   }



   @Override
   public final FormulaValue evaluate(FormulaValueReference[] arguments)
     throws FormulaFunctionCallException
  {

       StringValue dataStringArg = (StringValue)arguments[0].getFormulaValue();
       StringValue opzArg =(StringValue)arguments[1].getFormulaValue();

     String dataString = dataStringArg.getString();
     String opz=opzArg.getString();



    String returnVal = doTranslation(dataString,opz);

    return StringValue.fromString(returnVal);
   }

   @Override
   public final FormulaFunctionArgumentDefinition[] getArguments()
  {
     return this.myArguments;
  }

 @Override  
public final FormulaValueType getReturnType()
  {
     return FormulaValueType.string;
   }


   protected abstract String translate(String inputData,String opz)
   throws InvalidBarcodeDataException;

//protected abstract String translate(String inputData)
//throws InvalidBarcodeDataException;

 // private String translateCharWrapper(String inputData)
   private String translateCharWrapper(String inputData,String opz)
  {
     String returnString;

     try
    {
        // returnString = translate(inputData);
      returnString = translate(inputData,opz);
     } catch (InvalidBarcodeDataException e) {
      returnString = "";
     }

    return returnString;
  }



   @Override
   public void validateArgumentValues(FormulaValueReference[] arguments)
     throws FormulaFunctionCallException
   {}
 }
```

Comment: This link looks like a good start: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse143/11wi/eclipse-tutorial/junit.shtml

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. I've tried  to edit a junit test but I have some question to ask. How can I develop the method "evalute" with Junit? because has an array as paramater. I copied the code in the OP.